# Implementing geographical search in python-twitter

Tags: python, json, twitter

I am trying to get the tweets of nearby places. I can see lot of tweets using the following query

```
https://twitter.com/search?f=realtime&q=near:delhi%20within:5km
```

but I am not able to implement it using `python-twitter`. I would request someone to give implementation of the above mentioned link in `python-twitter`/`tweepy`. I found solution of similar queries in PHP but not in Python.

The problem is how to get authentication in new Twitter API before firing queries like API links  using `urllib` and avoid errors.

First I tried

```
neartweets= api.GetSearch("near:delhi within:5km")`
```

After authentication, got this error:

```
TwitterError: [{'message': 'near parameter is invalid.', 'code': 44}]
```

I also tried:

```
response = urllib.urlopen('https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json?f=realtime&q=near:delhi%20within:5km')
json.load(response)
```

But got

```
{'errors': [{'message': 'Bad Authentication data', 'code': 215}]}
```

Comment: Have you tried using the `geocode` parameter of `GetSearch` (*"geolocation information in the form `(latitude, longitude, radius)`"*)?

Comment: @ jonrsharpe ... I am trying {api.GetSearch(geocode=(28.61,77.23,5))} but not getting any tweets

Comment: Are you sure `radius` is in km? Try `5000` and see what happens.

Comment: @jonrsharpe   still not working

Comment: @jonrsharpe This is working but all tweets are not from Delhi . Not sure how twitter is tagging it to this coordinates , Also not all are "geodode=yes", delhi = api.GetSearch(geocode=("28.6100", "77.2300", "50mi"), count=1000)

Comment: Interesting - are all of the tweets with `geocode=yes` in Delhi? It could be that you get all tweets which are geocoded to Delhi *and* all tweets that aren't geocoded. Beyond that I haven't the foggiest!

Comment: Not actually only 3 to 5 % have geocode=yes .... Beside it I am not sure all are from delhi or not